Password protection Excel(.xlsx) file using Python in Databricks
I want to protect an Excel with password which is available in S3 bucket and save it back to s3, I tried with openpyxl and xlsxwriter, it is generating xlsx file, but it opens without asking for password
import openpyxl
import shutil

def password_protect_excel(filename, password):
# Load the workbook from the mount location
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)

    # Placeholder for password protection
    print(f"Attempting to set a password on the workbook: {password}")
    
    # Save the workbook to a local temporary path first
    temp_local_path = "/tmp/Report_temp.xlsx"
    workbook.save(temp_local_path)
    
    return temp_local_path

if __name__ == "__main__":
# Define the mount location paths
input_file = "/dbfs/mnt/file_mount_report/Report.xlsx"
output_file = "/dbfs/mnt/file_mount_report/Report_protected_new.xlsx"

    # Password placeholder
    password = "your_strong_password"
    
    # Step 1: Process the Excel file
    temp_local_path = password_protect_excel(input_file, password)
    
    # Step 2: Move the saved file to the mount location
    shutil.copy(temp_local_path, output_file)
    
    print(f"Workbook saved at {output_file}")


in your password_protect_excel function you are displaying the pwd but not setting it in your workbook.

Refer to this page for more details
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protection.html

To tie the bow on Ganesh's comments: after you load the workbook, add these lines:
workbook.security.workbookPassword = password
workbook.security.lockStructure = True

